# DOMXPath query returns zero results

Tags: php, curl, xpath

I'm an Xpath newbie. I have tested a query with my XPath Firefox plugin which returns a perfect result. However when I ran the query in PHP and do a var_dump(), I get no results. Just output similar to:

```
class DOMNodeList#4 (0) {
}
```

PHP accepts my expression as valid. So far I've removed the tbody that's part of my browser-generated query. In addition I've even tried to query for ("*") without any result. What else can I try? My query is below

```
$page = curl_exec($ch);

# Close the PHP/CURL session
curl_close($ch);

// Create new PHP DOM document
$dom = new DOMDocument;
// Load html from curl request into document model
@$dom->loadHTML($page);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

//$tableRows = $xpath->query("//id('divResults')/x:table/x:tbody/x:tr");
//$tableRows = $xpath->query("id('divResults')/table/tbody/tr");
//$tableRows = $xpath->query('/*');
$tableRows = $xpath->query('*');

var_dump($tableRows);
```

Comment: If you're using namespaces, you have to register them before. Only do so if your original document contains namespaces. The result of `$xpath->query` does return an element implementing the iterator interface, but does not contain data itself, thus you cannot use `ver_dump` on it.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, var_dump() does'nt work. Here's some code that gets the job done.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
if (!$dom->loadHTML($page)) throw new Exception (implode (",", libxml_get_errors()));
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$entries = $xpath->query($xpathExpr);
if (!$entries) throw new Exception ("XPath evaluation error");
foreach ($entries as $entry)
    echo "name: {$entry->nodeName}<br/>path: ".$entry->getNodePath()."<br/>value: {$entry->nodeValue}";
```